# preserve header when adding another worddocument without header

Tags: vba, ms-word, header, preserve

i use vba in wordfile A to add a word file B to the end of file A.
File A has a header(Kopfzeile), file B does not have this. When B is added in the end of A, all the headers in A are gone, but what i want is that the header of A is also on the added content of B
used code:

```
Set Doc_A = Documents.Open(path_A)
Doc_A.Range.InsertBreak (wdSectionBreakNextPage)
Selection.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
Selection.InsertFile FileName:=Path_B
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to unlink the header(s) in the new section. For example:

```
Set Doc_A = Documents.Open(path_A)
Doc_A.Range.InsertBreak (wdSectionBreakNextPage)
With Doc_A.Sections.Last
    .Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).LinkToPrevious = False
    .Range.Paragraphs.Last.Range.InsertFile FileName:=Path_B
End With
```

Comment: that does not work, the header are gone after inserting file B at the end.

Comment: It works perfectly for me. Simply inserting another document that doesn't have a page header won't affect existing headers in the document.

Comment: See: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43339-combine-multiple-word-documents.html